# Como passar valor null via json_encode

Tags: php, javascript, json

Como posso passar um json do php para jquery com valores null. Tenho a estrutura abaixo:

```
$data1 = null; $data2 = null; $data3 = null;
json_encode(array(
    'html'=>$html, 
    'data1'=>$data1, 
    'data2'=>$data2, 
    'data3'=>$data3)
);
```

O fato de passar null dá um erro:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Uso PHP `5.5.12`

Comment: Em 5.6 funciona bem https://ideone.com/fork/7hsBor. No http://phptester.net/ funciona com 5.5 e 5.4. De onde vem essa variável `$html`?

Comment: Eu monto parte do html no php e passo via json pela variável $html.

Comment: Está dando erro no JQuery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está passando o valor null corretamente. O problema que eu vejo no seu código é que você escreveu `$date3` no `json_encode()` ao invés de `$data3`. Fora que não está guardando o retorno do `json_encode`. Resolvendo isso, o código funcionou perfeitamente aqui.

Solução:

```
$data1 = null;
$data2 = null;
$data3 = null;

$json = json_encode(array(
  'html' => $html,
  'data1' => $data1,
  'data2' => $data2,
  'data3' => $data3
));;
```

Comment: O AP corrigiu isso, era um erro tipográfico.

Comment: Existia um erro do php para o jquery. Os dados iam fora do formato. Agora está ok.